# How to address the error "Your data directory is readable by other users" with ntfs-3g usermap

Tags: disk, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I use the command

```
ntfsusermap /dev/sda1
```

in order to generate a mapping file to use a NTFS usb external drive (that has already many files written under Windows in it) with debian based linux distro.
When I launch this command, this is what I see:

[image]

so I input 1000 that is my linux account UID and I get the message:

> You have defined no group, this can cause problems Do you accept
> defining a standard group ?

I don't know why, since it hasn't appeared any step where input the group GID, and apparently seems I have no choice to click enter to continue the mapping file creation with no group or abort the procedure.
The generated mapping file has following structure

```
# Generated by ntfsusermap for Linux, v 1.2.0
:p1:S-1-5-21-7728005000-258166423-2201256221-513
p1:p1:S-1-5-21-7728005000-258166423-2201256221-1001
```

And last line `S-1-5-21-7728005000-258166423-2201256221-1001`match exactly the SID of the Windows user account used to write the files already present on the external hard drive.

Now, If I try to use the mapping file generated in this way with some server applications I get the message

> Your data directory is readable by other users
>
> Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be
> listed by other users.

How should I map the drive to avoid similar problems?

Comment: The ntfsusermap command is looking at existing files on the filesystem and their Windows Security IDs. Apparently there are no files on the filesystem with a group SID that is not one of the standard ones (Administrators, etc.). If there are no group SID that could be mapped to a Linux group, it cannot ask about any groups. But the mapping file is just a text file with a specific format: if you know the SID of a Windows group you wish to map, nothing stops you from editing it in.

Comment: @telcoM The hard drive has already many existing files written under Windows (just with normal drag and drop on external USB drive without some specific setting). Do you mean that I have to input somewhere the SID of the Window account used to write them? Could you give me more details about what exactly I should do? (and how I should get the SID if needed).

Comment: @telcoM I have updated the question with additional details

Answer (score 0):

OK, you seem to have one user SID (the one ending in `-1001`) and one group SID (the one ending in `-513`) mapped to your Linux user account `p1` and its private group `p1` respectively.

When talking about SID mappings, it can be important to know a bit about [Windows well-known SIDs.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab)

A SID of the form `S-1-5-21-<domain_specific_part>-513` is a well-known SID for the *Domain Users* group, which includes all the regular domain user accounts.

When the SID mapping is in effect on the filesystem mounted with the NTFS-3g driver, you should be able to use the classic Unix-style `chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` commands, and the driver will automatically generate corresponding NTFS ACLs for you. If the classic Unix-style is too restrictive, you can also use `getfacl`/`setfacl` to use Posix-style ACLs (translated by the driver to NTFS ACLs) if this feature was enabled when your NTFS-3g driver was compiled.

The message

> Your data directory is readable by other users
>
> Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.

looks like the application in question is simply looking at the Unix-style permissions and finding them too lax for its taste. Apparently your data directory permissions, when viewed Unix-style, are at least `drwx???r-x`. Assuming that the Unix-style owner and group appear as `p1`, this means the actual underlying NTFS ACL will be as follows:

- user `p1`: Full Control
- Domain Users: ??? (you haven't disclosed any information that would tell me the permission setting, but the `p1` group currently maps to "Domain Users" well-known SID.)
- Everyone: Read (or perhaps even Full Control)

The application is worried about that last part. But its suggestion misses the mark: while using `chmod 770 <data_directory_pathname>` would probably avoid the error message, this would set full access for the group (the middle `7`, which maps to `rwx` for the group permissions)... and by the SID inspection, we now known that the group in question would actually be "Domain Users", to which every regular Windows user in the domain belongs! So it would not be much of a protection.

If the application's "data directory" is something that should be private, as the application seems to be suggesting, you have two options:

1.) You could leave the SID mapping as it is now, and use `chmod 700 <data_directory_pathname>` or `chmod go-rwx <data_directory_pathname>` to set the permissions of the application's data directory to `drwx------` when viewed from Linux, restricting access to that directory to the `p1` user only, both in Windows and Linux.

2.) Alternatively, you could create a suitable Windows **group** for the data directory, and perhaps even name the corresponding Linux group more descriptively than `p1`. Then either edit the SID of the Windows group onto the mapping file, or just re-run the `ntfsusermap` tool after using that Windows group in at least one NTFS ACL on the filesystem.

Since the application itself suggests permissions 0770 (ie. `drwxrwx---`) for its data directory, it probably won't complain about granting full access for the group - it's the last triplet of permissions (the "others" triplet, or in Windows terms, the `Everyone` ACL entry) it's worried about.

Comment: for the domain user matter I haven't understood how I should provide the information you are talking about. In windows seems that all the files copied on an usb external storage device have the *everyone* permission by default (and this is handy to manage the disk with others devices). If I use `chmod -R 770 <folderused as mountpoint>` it continues to complaint about data directory readable by other users in the same way and if I add `UUID=<MYDISKUID> /home/<mymountpoint> ntfs-3g defaults,dmode=770,fmode=660 0 0` in fstab when I mount drive it shows `There were no valid user or no valid group`